# how to check if wait cursor is displayed?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to tweak the cursor from Wait cursor to Normal before displaying a child dialog. And after the dialog is closed - want to tweak back to wait cursor after dialog is closed(Only if wait cursor was displayed before launching the dialog). So, how can check if wait cursor is being displayed in code.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why is the cursor set to wait before you open your dialog? Did you set it, and if so, how?

Comment: Nothing that a simple bool variable couldn't solve, I imagine.  If you *have* to then GetCursorInfo() can tell you what cursor is displayed.  Dialogs are meant to be interactive :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));  
...
HCURSOR hcurOld;
hcurOld = SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
CMyDialog dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
if (hcurOld) SetCursor(hcurOld);   // restore previous cursor
```

I prefer using the 'CWaitCursor' class though.